# How to stop Live Bind()

Tags: jquery, bind, live, unbind

I am trying to hide a `div` after a user clicks on the document.

```
<div class="active">
   <a class="agree" href="javascript:;">I Agree</a>
   <a class="disagree" href="javascript:;">Disagree</a>
</div>
```

Using the following solution -

```
var mouseOverActiveElement = false;

$('.active').live('mouseenter', function(){
    mouseOverActiveElement = true; 
}).live('mouseleave', function(){ 
    mouseOverActiveElement = false; 
});
$("html").click(function(){ 
    if (!mouseOverActiveElement) {
        //Do something special
    }
});
```

My problem is how can I `unbind` the `html` so that contents inside the `do something special` stop firing annd the whole thing starts again ?

At the moment - the `html.click();` keeps firing everytime ?

Comment: why don't you just bind live to div? html can be dangerous and inefficient.

Comment: this question is about `unbind`, not `die`.

Comment: @bluefoot - don't mind - just the best way to resolve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    var mouseOverActiveElement = false;

    $('.active').live('mouseenter', function(){
        mouseOverActiveElement = true; 
    }).live('mouseleave', function(){ 
        mouseOverActiveElement = false; 
    });
    $("html").click(function(){ 
        if (!mouseOverActiveElement) {
            //Do something special
            mouseOverActiveElement = false;

//If you want to unbind html click event then use $("html").unbind('click');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method:

```
$("html").unbind("click");
```